# How would I set a picture to the background like this document?

Tags: google-docs

Long story short, I'd like to be able to recreate a document, but I cannot get the background. I have been trying to copy it for the past few weeks, and to no avail, nothing has worked.

I know the drawings method, but if you go to MobileBasic, then you can select the text, showing that it's actual text.

Link: https://docs.google.com/document/d/12gkgFEgovVd56m5VefAgUjYtImeUkZtVoyFQYjD4_Jc/edit#

Thanks,
Rook.